Ansible - How to find if a value from a list exists in another registered variable?
I have set of numbers in the list db_home_desired_patches_list and I want to check if those numbers in the list, exist in another registered variable lspatches.
- name: Get opatch lspatches from dbhome_1
  shell: |
    $ORACLE_HOME/OPatch/opatch lspatches
  environment:
    ORACLE_HOME: "{{ db_home_1 }}"
    PATH: $ORACLE_HOME/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$PATH:/usr/bin
  register: lspatches
  failed_when:  ' db_home_desired_patches_list | difference (lspatches.stdout_lines) | length > 0 '

Sample of db_home_desired_patches_list
[
"35985645",
"35778398",
"35597425",
"34939189"
    ]

Ouput of $ORACLE_HOME/OPatch/opatch lspatches
35985645;EVEV-DEV2   DB CONTINUOUS RESTARTS WITH ORA-00600  INTERNAL ERROR CODE, ARGUMENTS  [KDIFIND KCBZ_OBJDCHK]
35778398;FURTHER FIXES FOR ROW CACHE ON TOP OF 34304965\n35098441;LOGMINER FAILS TO PURGE LOGMNRC_TSPART AND OTHER SHARD TABLES
35597425;ORA-600 723 IN RFS PROCESS\n34939189;TRAIL FILE CORRUPTION DBFS\n36130656;MERGE ON DATABASE RU 19.22.0.0.0 OF 36092993
35511348;AIM ORA-7445 [KNLCAPINSPROC] - KNLCAPINSPROC\n36130831;MERGE ON DATABASE RU 19.22.0.0.0 OF 35989319


The Conditional with
db_home_desired_patches_list | difference (lspatches.stdout_lines)

probably won't work because the output of opatch lspatches is a Character Separated Value (CSV) list with delimiter semicolon (;) whereby you would need the first column only.
A quick and lazy approach splitting on the delimiter by pre-processing is shown in the following minimal example
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    desired_patches: [
      "35985645",
      "35778398",
      "35597425",
      "34939189"
    ]

  tasks:

  - shell:
      cmd: 'cat lspatches | cut -d ";" -f 1'
    register: installed_patches

  - debug:
      msg: "Missing patches: {{ desired_patches | difference(installed_patches.stdout_lines) }}"

resulting into an output of
TASK [debug] ***************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 'Missing patches: [''34939189'']'

An add-on could be
  - debug:
      msg: "Patches applied but not in the list: {{ installed_patches.stdout_lines | difference(desired_patches) }}"

resulting into an output of
TASK [debug] ***********************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 'Patches applied but not in the list: [''35511348'']'

If interested in Ansible: How to access a stored CSV ..., within the given link and other similar Q&A there are already answers provided here on StackOverflow. As well for how to do the post-processing within in Ansible
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ installed_patches.stdout_lines | map('split', ';') | map('first') | list }}"


resulting into an output of
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - '35985645'
  - '35778398'
  - '35597425'
  - '35511348'

Documentation and Similar Q&A

difference filter – the difference of one list from another

Ansible: How to use split strings based on a delimiter using maps for items present in list?



It might be better to distribute the work and tasks over the different systems instead of doing it all within the playbook.
In example, a cron job exporting the installed patches into a CSV file on a frequent base will provide the option to use the read_csv module – Read a CSV file, preventing the usage of the shell module and "scripting" or "programming" within the playbook.
And even better, if implementing it as Custom fact will lead into the option to just query the facts about the system, the patches installed like any other Ansible facts.

The following self-explanatory playbook:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # Faking your registered value
    lspatches:
      stdout_lines:
        - 35985645;EVEV-DEV2   DB CONTINUOUS RESTARTS WITH ORA-00600  INTERNAL ERROR CODE, ARGUMENTS  [KDIFIND KCBZ_OBJDCHK]
        - 35778398;FURTHER FIXES FOR ROW CACHE ON TOP OF 34304965\n35098441;LOGMINER FAILS TO PURGE LOGMNRC_TSPART AND OTHER SHARD TABLES
        - 35597425;ORA-600 723 IN RFS PROCESS\n34939189;TRAIL FILE CORRUPTION DBFS\n36130656;MERGE ON DATABASE RU 19.22.0.0.0 OF 36092993
        - 35511348;AIM ORA-7445 [KNLCAPINSPROC] - KNLCAPINSPROC\n36130831;MERGE ON DATABASE RU 19.22.0.0.0 OF 35989319
    
    # Extract patch numbers only.
    # Note: this can stay "static" and will work with a registered var.
    # The only prereq is that the register exists prior to using that var.
    # You can harden this by using `default` if needed
    installed_patches_list: "{{ lspatches.stdout_lines | map('regex_replace', '^(\\d*);.*$', '\\1') }}"

    db_home_desired_patches_list:
      - "35985645"
      - "35778398"
      - "35597425"
      - "34939189"

  tasks:
    - name: Show original variable as a simple check
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: lspatches.stdout_lines

    - name: Show extracted patch numbers
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: installed_patches_list

    - name: Show the actual difference between lists
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: db_home_desired_patches_list | difference (installed_patches_list)

    - name: Run test as present in the question (refactored with new list)
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Patch list on db is different than desired one"
      when: db_home_desired_patches_list | difference (installed_patches_list) | length > 0

Runs as you expect:
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show original variable as a simple check] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "lspatches.stdout_lines": [
        "35985645;EVEV-DEV2   DB CONTINUOUS RESTARTS WITH ORA-00600  INTERNAL ERROR CODE, ARGUMENTS  [KDIFIND KCBZ_OBJDCHK]",
        "35778398;FURTHER FIXES FOR ROW CACHE ON TOP OF 34304965\\n35098441;LOGMINER FAILS TO PURGE LOGMNRC_TSPART AND OTHER SHARD TABLES",
        "35597425;ORA-600 723 IN RFS PROCESS\\n34939189;TRAIL FILE CORRUPTION DBFS\\n36130656;MERGE ON DATABASE RU 19.22.0.0.0 OF 36092993",
        "35511348;AIM ORA-7445 [KNLCAPINSPROC] - KNLCAPINSPROC\\n36130831;MERGE ON DATABASE RU 19.22.0.0.0 OF 35989319"
    ]
}

TASK [Show extracted patch numbers] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "installed_patches_list": [
        "35985645",
        "35778398",
        "35597425",
        "35511348"
    ]
}

TASK [Show the actual difference between lists] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "db_home_desired_patches_list | difference (installed_patches_list)": [
        "34939189"
    ]
}

TASK [Run test as present in the question (refactored with new list)] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Patch list on db is different than desired one"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

